# WPF ShowDialog() is showing multiple Windows

Tags: wpf, dialog, modal-dialog, window, showdialog

I have created 3 Windows with very basic components. I noticed some very strange behavior. 
If I create an instance of each Window but only use ShowDialog() on one of them then all 3 windows display.

```
Window1 w1 = new Window1();
Window2 w2 = new Window2();
Window3 w3 = new Window3();
w3.ShowDialog();
```

All 3 windows display. Only w3 shows as a modal window as I've launched it via ShowDialog(). w1 and w2 show as if i had used Show(). I dont understand how this is happening!

If i do this then they all launch one at a time.

```
Window1 w1 = new Window1();
w1.ShowDialog(); 
Window2 w2 = new Window2();
w2.ShowDialog(); 
Window3 w3 = new Window3();
w3.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: This won't happen without something else going on. Something in the constructors perhaps or maybe a partial class thing. Could you share an example?

Comment: I know it shouldnt but i cant figure out how. Ive searched my entire solution for ShowDialog() and Show() but didnt find anything out of the ordinary. Are there any other ways to show a Window?

Comment: Without a [minimal complete reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't help with this.

Comment: Do `w1` and `w2` also open, when you replace `w3.ShowDialog()` with `w3.Show()`?

Comment: Here is what I'd do. Hook up "Loaded" on say Window2 and add a breakpoint. Reproduce the problem and look at the callstack.

Comment: @Herdo If i just use Show i see the correct window but its frozen. Weird

Comment: @DavidHollinshead I looked at the call stack and between my ShowDialog and the Loaded event in w2 there is nothing except .Net core dll methods

Comment: I'd be interested in that call stack. Maybe compare it to a call stack from the Loaded event for Window3. The Window3 call stack should have a button click (or whatever) in it. How does the Window2 callstack differ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with .NET 4.5 on Windows 8. Maybe it's an OS issue?